# appending a column to an existing file in fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm am trying to write a script that creates an output file with all my data, but my data has different lengths. So I was thinking of writing one file, then adding a new column to it with the other data. I am open to any other suggestions.

So, for example, I would write one file with 3 columns with all my coordinates, then later add a fourth column including temperature or something. the coordinates would have a longer line length since they are measured more frequently.

this is what I've tried before

```
24      format(a4, 1x, 2(ES12.4, 1x),i4, 1x, f8.3,1x,ES12.4,1x, 3(i4,1x))  
25      format(20x, f8.3,1x,ES12.4,1x, 3(i4,1x))

do while (.true.)
read(unit=802,fmt=2,end=122)coll2,t2,ered,tred,hb_alpha,hb_ii,hb_ij,ehh_ii,ehh_ij,rg_avg,e2e_avg
write(8,25) ttotal+t, hb_alpha,hb_ii-hb_alpha,hb_ij, colltotal+coll
end do 

write(8,24) fname_digits, ttotal+t, colltotal+coll, betahb
```

everything is within another `do`-loop to read from one file to the next. the variables in the `do`-loop have a longer length than the variables in the second `write` statement.

I would expect all the data in one file, with varying line lengths.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question should contain the complete code in the form of a [mcve] and the description of the problem you have with the code in a sufficient detail. Note that you should ask an actual question.

Comment: *So I was thinking of writing one file, then adding a new column to it with the other data. I am open to any other suggestions*  Better to think of reading the existing file line-by-line, appending the necessary item(s), and writing a new file line-by-line.  Amending a file in-place is just not worth the trouble unless you have a database management system (or similar) to write.

Comment: A file can be seen as a 1D linear array of bytes. Adding a column on one line implies shifting all the subsequent lines forwards in the file. So in practice you must rewrite the entire file. See comment by @HighPerformanceMark